# Lighttpd configuration for www in domain name

Tags: lighttpd, url

My website does not appear when I navigate to www.url.com, but it does work for url.com

This is my lighttpd config:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^url.com$" {
  server.document-root = "/home/a/www/url.com"
  server.error-handler-404 = "/index.php"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emthigious is only partially correct,

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "url.com$" {
```

is a somewhat ambiguous match
it would match www.url.com
but it would also match

- anotherurl.com
- someotherurl.com
- mail.url.com

etc

a better solution would be:

```
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^(www\.)?url.com$" {
```

This will only match:

- url.com
- www.url.com

Answer (score 1):

emills is right, you'll have to change the regex to

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "url.com$" {
```

Now everything that ends with "url.com" wil be caught by the host-definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about lighttpd but the ^ at the beginning of "^url.com$" looks like it means "starts with" which means that only exactly "url.com" will be accepted by that declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Who manages the authoritative name server url.com? You could just add an entry for 'www' pointing to your web server.